# Invalid Host Header error when running an Angular project

Tags: angular, frontend, backend, web-development-server, angular-fullstack

Invalid Host Header error when running an Angular project ,
I tried those below:
First:
"serve": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
"options": {
"browserTarget": "yourProject:build",
"host": "0.0.0.0", // Add
"disableHostCheck": true // Add
},
...
}

Second:
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check

Third:
ng serve --open --host $IP --port $PORT --disable-host-check

I tried those below:
First:
"serve": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
"options": {
"browserTarget": "yourProject:build",
"host": "0.0.0.0", // Add
"disableHostCheck": true // Add
},
...
}

Second:
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check

Third:
ng serve --open --host $IP --port $PORT --disable-host-check

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.